# Issue of deployment using glassfish server

Tags: java, xml, glassfish, glassfish-3, netbeans-7

I am using glassfish server.. the application was running smoothly but all of sudden i started getting this message.

```
build-impl.xml:1073:
```

Could any suggest me on how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you upgrade you netbeans or glassfish recently?
This problem happens sometime when you performed an upgrade with the netbeans IDE or some modules of it.
If you did, you had better try to create a new project or re-install the application in the glassfish again. This may help.
By the way, could you please provide some detailed information so that we can perform some further investigation.

Comment: well i am working in Affablebean projects in Netbeans. I used JPA (Entity class) and EJB to query data instead of using JSTL tag. I created Session beans and Entity class using netbeans, when i deployed the application it showed HTTP 500 status that it could not find cat_id property in entity.category class. I then searched and look for solution, i have even posted it in stack overflow, i got no response so i thought of deleting all the classes and then start it again, i deleted and deployed, i started to get this message.I dont even see my project in Application folder of Glassfish Server.

Answer (score 0):

well i don't think it is the good solution however i did not find any other option then the one i have mentioned below to solve this problem.

I uninstalled the GlassFish Server and installed latest version i.e. 4.0 ( You can install the same version, it should work) and then i removed the project from netbeans Projects list. I again created a new project and copied all the required files from the previous project. It worked. The application is now deployed in GlassFish Server 4.0.

However this solution to me is like formatting computer when you cannot solve the problem raised in your PC. If someone could tell me the reason and the way to solve the problem mention above i would be very thankful.

Anyways thanks to Mr lowitty for the suggestion.